# powershell output of ad-user pwdLastSet and LastLoginTimeStamp

Tags: powershell, active-directory, output

I'm working on a script that will run down a csv of LastName and FirstName of users on a domain and return someinfo about them in another csv.

Returning the properties is not an issue, but when I try to convert pwdLastSet and LastLogonTimeStamp to a readable format, it crashes when writing to the csv.

Here is my code.  in this example, pwdLastSet will result in an unreadable 64bit number.

```
$names = import-csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\input.csv
$users = @()

foreach ($name in $names){

    $filter = "givenName -like ""*$($name.FirstName)*"" -and sn -like ""$($name.LastName)"""
    $users += get-aduser -filter $filter -Properties * | select-object employeeID, sn, givenName, distinguishedName, whencreated, passwordnotrequired, enabled, admincount, pwdlastset
}

$users | select employeeID, sn, givenName, distinguishedName, whencreated, passwordnotrequired, enabled, admincount, pwdlastset | export-csv c:\users\me\desktop\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I'd like to throw *$([datetime]::FromFileTime($user.pwdLastSet))* so it's readable in the output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to replace the value of a property or create an additional property:

```
$users += Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties * |
    select employeeID, ..., admincount,
           @{n='pwdLastSet';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)}}
```

In this case it's an unnecessary step, though, because `Get-ADUser` already did that for you and placed that value in the `PasswordLastSet` property, as [@user3815146](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24625932/1630171) already pointed out (+1).

To get an overview of the properties of a user object you can use the [`Get-Member`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) cmdlet:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property * | Get-Member
```

or list the members of any given user object:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity 'someuser' -Property * | Format-List *
```

---

On a more general note: **never** append to an array in a loop. The construct

```
$arr = @()
foreach ($item in $list) {
  $arr += Do-StuffWith $item
}
```

guarantees poor performance, because with each iteration a new array is created (size + 1) and all elements are copied from the old array to the new one. Using a `ForEach-Object` loop in a pipeline provides *far* better performance:

```
$arr = $list | ForEach-Object { Do-StuffWith $_ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `pwdLastSet`, try using `PasswordLastSet`.

On a different note, have you considered shortening your command to this:

```
$users += get-aduser -filter $filter -Properties employeeID,sn,givenName,distinguishedName, whencreated,passwordnotrequired,enabled,admincount,passwordlastset
```

Comment: The `-Properties` parameter is inclusive, not exclusive, i.e. you get the specified properties in addition to the default property set (which includes things like SID, objectGUID and user principal name). Because of that he still needs to `select` the desired set of attributes.